# Performing Binary Search

Tags: r, recursion, binary-search

I'm trying to perform binary search using recursion in R. This is what I have written:

```
num <- c(5, 10, 13, 55, 67, 99)
## i = low , j = high
binary_search <- function(num, i, j, x) {
  if (j <= i) 
    m <- ((i+j) / 2)
  if (x == num[m]){
    return(m) 
  } else if (x < num[m]) { 
    return(binary_search(num, i, m - 1, x))
  } else if (x > num[m]) { 
    return (binary_search(num, m + 1, j, x))
  }
}
i <- 0
j <- length(num)
binary_search(num, i, j, 99)
```

It does not show any error in the console, however the result only shows
`Error: C stack usage  15923024 is too close to the limit`

Did I perhaps make a mistake in my code? I'm still a newbie, would love any help, thanks!

Comment: Well, the second if-clasue does not know what 'm' is. In case of 'j > i', 'm' is not assigned, so there is no 'num[m]'. Maybe there more mistakes. Didn't check it further.

Comment: As written I don't get that error. The first `if` is FALSE so `m` isn't computed and I get `object 'm' not found`

Comment: `m` is okay when  `i` is actually `>` `j`,  say i is 7, j 6, and in effect must be calculated for this logic as i 4, j 6, leads to `object 'm' not found`. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Looking at the notes `## i = low , j = high`, was the thought to first test i & j as entered and swap them around if in improper order of low to high?, or perhaps send them off to a different algorithm for adjudication given the case?

Comment: @Mischa Thank you, that is very helpful! I changed the first if clause into ```while()``` and now m is assigned for the next if clause.

Comment: @Chris Yes, I made a silly but huge mistake right there which I just noticed! I've corrected it to ```i<j``` and it works just fine now, lots of thanks!

Comment: So, put/edit in your correction above, perhaps with a trailing # comment denoting the change for future searchers seeking resolution.